# Regex pattern to separate string with semicolon and plus

Tags: c#, regex

Here I have used the below mentioned code.

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(cellData, @"(^\[.*\]$|^\[.*\]_[0-9]*$)");
```

The only this pattern is not doing is it's not separating the semicolon and plus from the main string.

A sample string is

```
[dbServer];[ciDBNAME];[dbLogin];[dbPasswd] AND [SIM_ErrorFound@1]_+[@IterationCount]
```

I am trying to extract

```
[dbServer]
[ciDBNAME]
[dbLogin]
[dbPasswd]
[SIM_ErrorFound@1]
[@IterationCount]
```

from the string.

Comment: Are you sure that is the only problem with this pattern? Please show some input strings and expected outputs.

Comment: [dbServer];[ciDBNAME];[dbLogin];[dbPasswd]
AND
[SIM_ErrorFound@1]_+[@IterationCount]

Is not getting split.

Comment: Do you mean you just want to extract `[...]` substrings? Try a regex like [`@"\[[^][]+]"`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%5d&i=%5bdbServer%5d%3b%5bciDBNAME%5d%3b%5bdbLogin%5d%3b%5bdbPasswd%5d+AND+%5bSIM_ErrorFound%401%5d_%2b%5b%40IterationCount%5d).

Comment: You should add the sample string and the expected output to the question.

Comment: Thanks, Wiktor Stribiżew your solution work's for me.

Comment: Good, I posted a full answer with explanation and a code snippet. I also added the details to make the question answerable to the question itself. Please do not forget to do that next time you ask a question to avoid downvotes and close votes.

Comment: Sure from next time I'll remember that. And once again thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract the stuff in square brackets from `[dbServer];[ciDBNAME];[dbLogin];[dbPasswd] AND [SIM_ErrorFound@1]_+[@IterationCount]` (which is what I assume you're be trying to do),

The regular expression (I haven't quoted it) should be

`\[([^\]]*)\]`

You should not use `^` and `$` as youre not interested in start and end of strings.  The parentheses will capture every instance of zero or more characters inside square brackets.
If you want to be more specific about what you're capturing in the brackets, you'll need to change the `[^\]` to something else.

Comment: What if OP needs to also *validate* the string? This won't help then and the anchors will be necessary.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew,  agree, but what I posted was based on a guess as to what the OP was trying to do, which was simply to capture the db connection string params (a pretty common task) EDIT: Looks like OP was happy with the sugestion in your comment :)

Answer (score 1):

Your regex - `(^\[.*\]$|^\[.*\]_[0-9]*$)` - matches any full string that starts with `[`, then contains zero or more chars other than a newline, and ends with  `]` (`\]$`) or with `_` followed with 0+ digits (`_[0-9]*$`). You could also write the pattern as `^\[.*](?:_[0-9]*)?$` and it would work the same.

However, you need to match multiple substrings inside a larger string. Thus, you should have removed the `^` and `$` anchors and retried. Then, you would find out that `.*` is too greedy and matches from the first `[` up to the last `]`. To fix that, it is best to use a *negated character class* solution. E.g. you may use `[^][]*` that matches 0+ chars other than `[` and `]`.

Edit: It seems you need to get only the text inside square brackets.

You need to use a *capturing group*, a pair of unescaped parentheses around the part of the pattern you need to get and then access the value by the group ID (unnamed groups are numbered starting with 1 from left to right):

```
var results = Regex.Matches(s, @"\[([^][]+)]")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value)
    .ToList();
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%5b%28%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%29%5d&i=%5bdbServer%5d%3b%5bciDBNAME%5d%3b%5bdbLogin%5d%3b%5bdbPasswd%5d+AND+%5bSIM_ErrorFound%401%5d_%2b%5b%40IterationCount%5d)
[image]